# put value in jsonArray in android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to put jsonobject in jsonarray so that i can display the selected item.I tried but values are getting overwrite. Please help

```
if(myPrefs.getInt("product"+productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(),0)<10) {
                        qtyValues = myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), 0);
                        qtyValues = qtyValues + 1;
                        editor.putInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), qtyValues);
                        editor.commit();
                        holder.qtyCounter.setText(myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), 0) + "");
                        value = productBean.getProductPrice();
                        add(addItem);
                        amount(value);
                        System.out.println("ProductAdapter.isSKU------------========================" + ProductAdapter.isSKU);
                        setCartItem(productBean.getSkuId1(),myPrefs.getInt("product" + productBean.getProductId() + productBean.getSkuId1(), 0),productBean.getProductId(),productBean.getDescription() , productBean.getProductName() , productBean.getProductPrice());
                    }

jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("skuId",skuId);
        jsonObject.put("quantity",qty);
        jsonObject.put("productId",productId);
        jsonObject.put("price",price);
        jsonObject.put("productName",productName);
        jsonObject.put("description",description);

        editor.putString("data",jsonObject.toString());
        editor.commit();
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i have set of values which i need to send to cart so i am saving pId,qty and other stuff in json array which will be saved in sp.what is happening right now is values are getting overwrite in json i guess its not creating array

Comment: post you full code as i am unable to guess anything about your `JsonArray`

Comment: In array i want to save skuId, qty,price and stuffs

Answer (score 0):

you should put your jsonObject in jsonArray like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
```

I think you are using `putString`

**EDIT: How to fetch jsonObjects from jsonArray**
JSONArray objects have a function `getJSONObject(int index)`, you can loop through all of the JSONObjects by writing a simple for-loop:

```
JSONArray array;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    // do your stuff....
}
```

Comment: how can I fetch the array?

Comment: can you please explain me a bit as i am getting no values displayed.

Comment: 1) Are you adding jsonObjects in jsonArray? 2) Is that jsonArray initialized out of the loop? 3) Are you accessing the same jsonArray to getJSONObject?

Comment: i am saving my json in sp which i am fetching in different activity.

Comment: Debug your jsonArray after you call put method to insert jsonObjects. Are they inserted correctly or not.